# Regex - match all the dots "." before "=" in a given string

Tags: regex

Example string:

```
app.name=blah
project.version=1.0
```

I only want to match the dots "." before the equals sign "=".

Any help would be appreciated, tried a few regex but no success so far :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\.(?=.*=)`

The above is the regex I was looking for

`\.` -> escaped literal string "."

`(?=.*=)` -> positive lookahead group. This to make sure it only looks in the string before "="